# ActiveMQ Artemis DLQ address with copy of each message placed in DLQ.queue?

Tags: activemq-artemis

We probably encounter a problem with the "DLQ" address (with "queue stat" command) which count more than 3,6 millions messages (MESSAGE_COUNT and MESSAGE_ADDED).

In case of auto-create-queue (we have one DLQ queue for each origin queue prefixed with "DLQ.", all messages placed in DLQ are they copied to the "DLQ" address?

I asked for the persistent size of this address and it is very big (12 GB).
Please see how I get this information below:
[image]
Why is it so big?
How can I configure the "DLQ" address to minimize this persistent size?

I have check the persistent size on all DLQ : the "DLQ" address persistent size is bigger than all DLQ queues.
It seem to confirm that all messages placed in DLQ are copied to the "DLQ" address.

All messages in DLQ. queues are finally consumed. Only this "DLQ" address still contains all messages which were sent to DLQ. queues.
How can I purge this address safely and regularly?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you're using **both** a statically configured generally DLQ (i.e. the anycast queue named `DLQ` on the address named `DLQ`) *and* dynamically created individual DLQs (i.e. all the multicast queues prefixed with `DLQ.` on the address named `DLQ`). When a message is sent to the dead-letter address (i.e. `DLQ`) then it is routed to *all* the applicable queues which means the queue named `DLQ` will get every message and since you likely don't have a consumer on that queue messages will accumulate there.

I recommend you delete it via the web console and remove it from `broker.xml` so it doesn't come back the next time you start the broker.

Aside from that it appears that the application(s) connected to the broker are failing to consume a significant number of messages. This in itself should be investigated to prevent this kind of accumulation in the first place.

Also, if you want messages sent to any address whose name starts with `DLQ.` to expire after a certain amount of time then you can apply the [`expiry-delay` `address-setting`](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/address-settings.html) to `DLQ.#`

To be clear, an address can't actually store messages. Messages are only stored in queues. An address is simply a way to link queues to a routing-type so that when a message is sent to the address is gets routed to the appropriate queue.

Comment: Thank you Justin, why the persistent size of "DLQ" address is so big  (12 Gb) plz ?

Comment: An address doesn't have a "persistent size" attribute so I'm not exactly sure what you're looking at. You should add more details with maybe some screenshots to your question.

Comment: I have added a screenshot to explain how I get the "persistent size" attribute. Thank you for your support.

Comment: I updated my answer to address your comment. Hope that helps!